# Kubernetes Jobs backOffLimit

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

[image]

Is this diagram correct? Because, activeDeadlineSeconds takes precedence over backOffLimit, if activeDeadlineSeconds exceeded it should directly mark the job as incomplete right? Why is this checking backOffLimit if activeDeadlineSeconds exceeded?

Comment: that image is 50% empty space and the rest is so small nobody can read the text, so **no**, that diagram cannot be correct - it contains zero information for the reader, as it's impossible to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two parameters serve different purposes. In most cases  **ActiveDeadlineSeconds** takes **precedence** over **backoffLimit** because **activedeadline** is a hard limit on the **amount of time** that an operation is allowed to take. If **activeDeadlineSeconds** exceeds then all the pods will **terminate** and mark the job as **failure** with **reason: DeadlineExceeded**. Whereas the **backofflimit** is a limit on the **number of tries** that are attempted. However the specific precedence will depend on the **implementation** of the API or **application system**, as different systems may **prioritize** these parameters differently.

The scheduling of **cronjobs** will be as follows

1. On **scheduling** a cron job.
2. It will create a normal **job**.
3. Job will create a Pod.
4. If Pod has **Error** it will check whether the **backoffLimit** is exceeded
   or not.
5. If Yes, then it will mark the job as **incomplete**.
6. If No, then it will check if the **activeDeadlineSeconds exceeded** or
   not.
7. If **activeDeadlineSeconds does not exceed** then the job is marked as
   complete.
8. If it is **exceeded** then it will **mark as failure with reason
   DeadlineExceeded**.

For more information refer to this [official k8 document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-termination-and-cleanup)

Comment: What if activeDeadlineSeconds exceeded before even trying activeDeadlineSeconds?

Comment: Can you please **elaborate** your question. Because it is not clear. On the other note If you set the activeDeadlineSeconds limit very less than the time required for a pod to complete the necessary shutdown procedures then it will get **forcefully** terminated.